# help needed for preventing html injection

Tags: php, mysql

i have searched everywhere for knowing how to prevent html injection.i have also put two questions in this website.but  i didnt got a convincing answer.below this, i am giving my script which i made for preventing mysql,html injection in my html form.

```
     //sql injection prevention
      $name =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
     $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

 //striping tags
   $user =strip_tags($user);
  $login = strip_tags($login);
   $name =strip_tags($name);
```

after this i tried to check how well my script is working by using the below script and putting it in name,login,user form in my html and saving it in my database

```
 <script>
 document.location = "http://badurl";
</script>
```

but when i saved the above script in database and tried to retrieve it for showing in page it went to the badurl site.i think strip_tags is not working i want to know why. and can you please tell me how we can put htmlspecialchars in a while loop(like the script below)

```
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
    echo('<big><big><big style="color: rgb(158, 0, 0);">' . $row['name'] .  '&nbsp;&nbsp;</big></big></big><p>');
   echo('<big><div style="text-align: justify;">' . $row['login'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;</big>   </div>');

   echo('<div style="text-align: justify;">' . $row['user'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
```

Comment: You do not need to call `strip_tags` or anything else except `mysql_real_escape_string` before putting data into the database. Don't destroy the data because you can never get it back if you do it wrong. *When you go to display it in an HTML webpage*, you can use `htmlspecialchars` as in Dogbert's answer below.

Comment: thanks grossman for the reply

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the fields before printing them.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
    echo('<big><big><big style="color: rgb(158, 0, 0);">' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) .  '&nbsp;&nbsp;</big></big></big><p>');
   echo('<big><div style="text-align: justify;">' . htmlspecialchars($row['login']) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;</big>   </div>');

   echo('<div style="text-align: justify;">' . htmlspecialchars($row['user']) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Yeah.. in the UTF8 days `htmlspecialchars` is the way to go. No need to use entities for umlauts etc.

Comment: thanks dogbert for your excellent answer,it worked.i have one more doubt,can you tell me how to add htmlspecialchar to this script[echo("<big><big><a href=view.php?id=$link[id] class=y>$link[title]</a></big></big><br>");].this script will show title of a article and when clicked it will go to the article page.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library instead of raw php functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all tags all together, then use strip_tags.

If you want to encode the tags then use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities.

If you want to selectively remove tags that might lead to an injection but allow other tags, then you might want to look into implementing a solution using domdocument.